# How to Scroll rasperry pi 7'' Display in Midory Browser rather than marking

Tags: touchscreen, kiosk-mode

I use midory as an Fullscreen-App with an Raspberry 7'' Display. Is there any way to use the Touchscreen for scrolling in the browser? (I deactivated the Scrollbar because the design isnt fine for my app)